# How to alter a unique identifier of a node without violating the constraint

Tags: neo4j, cypher

After creating a node with a unique identifier with constraint set on it, is it possible to do the following later regarding changing the identifier:

if the value the identifier is changed to does not violate the constraint, the identifier will be changed to that variable;
if value the identifier is changed to does violate the constraint, the node (along with the relationships connected to it) will be deleted.

More specifically:

Constraint is set:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (addr:Address) ASSERT addr.uniqueReferenceAddr IS UNIQUE
```

Node is createded:

```
MERGE MERGE (a:Address {uniqueReferenceAddr:...}) 
ON CREATE SET a.AddID = ...,...
```

Then according to certain condition, the property `uniqueReferenceAddr` of the node with label :Address  might be changed, which might result in violating the constraint, if the value it is changed to is the same as a value already existed.

Is there any way around that?

Comment: catch the error, create a `:DuplicateAddress` node, attach it to the one it is a duplicate of and send it to some duplicate disambiguation process? OR drop the uniqueness constraint?